# View excel file in edit mode while running visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have Button1_click to open a Excel file,but the excel file is hide behind the visual basic. How to view the excel file and make it as edit mode although the visual basic program is running?

Answer (score 1):

Just change the userform option (showmodal = True), Then can edit the excel while the visual basic still running. :)